# Automatically triggered a function in a onClick while mounting the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

In react js, if someone used list object mapping to a list as follow:

```
const removeUser = (email)=>{
        alert(email)
    }

    const usersList = users.map((user) =>
        <li key={user._id}>
            {user.Name}
            { isAdmin && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt}  onClick={removeuser(user.Email)}/>}
        </li>
    );
```

in here, the function inside onClick event is automatically triggered when mounting the list elements component. it will prompt alerts with email addresses automatically.

Comment: This: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react` - `onClick` should get a function to execute, not execute a function like you did.

Wrap your function with arrow key function like this and it will work:

```
const removeUser = (email) => {
    alert(email)
}

const usersList = users.map((user) =>
    <li key={user._id}>
        {user.Name}
        {isAdmin && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt}  onClick={() => removeuser(user.Email)}/>}
    </li>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the invocation of the method, you should pass a definition of a method instead.

```
const usersList = users.map((user) => (
     <li key={user._id}>
        { user.Name }
       { isAdmin && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} onClick={() => removeuser(user.Email)} /> }
      </li>
 ));
```

Comment: '{}` in the wrong place. please correct.

Comment: sorry @RandyCasburn , I submited by mistake :->

Comment: This is what happens, when try to wrap everything in one line 

Comment: what is still incorrect? @RandyCasburn

Comment: that's what happen trying to help from the phone....

Comment: Fixed it @RandyCasburn

Comment: It's Ok @SoniaAguilar, No worries, you're doing good!!

Comment: thank you @Naren ... I'm not going to answer by my phone any more

Comment: "_answer by my phone_" - I learned that lesson too :-)

Comment: Same here, haha...